# How can I get the first word in a discord message using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi so for a project i want to get the first word of message ( it will be an @ and after it I will remove a role but don't dwell on it )

I can't show my code because it will need a few dozen minutes of explaining some random things ( because it use other bots )

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of what you've tried as this will help you narrow down what the question is. For example, if you've already got the message, is your question really about discord.py or is it more about how to manipulate a string? Either way, please see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by splitting the message content with the `.split()` method into a list, and then getting the first element of that list.

Message I send in the discord:

> This is a test for stackoverflow

output in the console:

> full message: This is a test for stackoverflow
>
> first word: "This"

code:

```
@bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
    full_message = message.content
    first_word_of_message = message.content.split()[0]

    print(f'full message: {full_message}')
    print(f'first word: "{first_word_of_message}"')
```